# Android crashing with fatal execption main java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to package

Tags: android

I'm doing sort of fetching listview database from the phpmyadmin to Android. I keep getting the crashing when entering the food page. I have no error with my code and I check my android monitor I see the error.

```
04-25 00:12:17.273 1731-1731/com.fypunimas.fyp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.xxxx, PID: 1731
                                                             java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.xxxx.Food
                                                                 at com.xxxx.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:66)
                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2486)
                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1970)
                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:765)
                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1744)
                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2266)
                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17723)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5739)
                                                                 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1197)
                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17723)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5739)
                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17723)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5739)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17723)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5739)
                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17723)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5739)
                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17723)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5739)
                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:874)
                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17723)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5739)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2350)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1258)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6468)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:908)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:720)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:655)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:894)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6256)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:793)
```

From the error, it state the statement"final Food foods=(Food)getItem(position);"has some problem. My code for customadapter.activity is as below

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public ArrayList<String> stringlist;
private Context context;
CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> stringlist) {
    //super(context, R.layout.item_food, stringlist);
    this.context = context;
    this.stringlist = stringlist;
}

public int getCount(){
    return stringlist.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position){
    return stringlist.get(position);

}

public long getItemId(int position){
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    final ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
    View customView;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
    LayoutInflater menuInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   // LayoutInflater menuInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    customView = menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_food, parent, false);
        listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
       // final String singlemenuitem = (String) getItem(position);
        listViewHolder.tvfoodname = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.tvfoodname);
        listViewHolder.btnadd = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
        listViewHolder.btnminus = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.btnminus);
        listViewHolder.etquantity = (EditText) customView.findViewById(R.id.etquantity);
        customView.setTag(listViewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        customView=convertView;
        listViewHolder= (ListViewHolder) customView.getTag();
    }

  //  listViewHolder.tvfoodname.setText(singlemenuitem);
    final Food foods=(Food)getItem(position);
    listViewHolder.tvfoodname.setText(foods.getFoodname());
    listViewHolder.etquantity.setText(foods.cartQuantity);
    listViewHolder.btnadd.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);
    listViewHolder.btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
   //   Food.cartQuantity=Integer.parseInt(etquantity.getText().toString().trim());
   //         Food.cartQuantity =  Food.cartQuantity + 1;
   //         etquantity.setText("" +  Food.cartQuantity);
            updateQuantity(position,listViewHolder.etquantity,1);
        }
    });
    listViewHolder.btnminus.setImageResource(R.drawable.minus);
    listViewHolder.btnminus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
   //         Food.cartQuantity = Integer.parseInt(etquantity.getText().toString().trim());
      //      if ( Food.cartQuantity == 0) {
    //            Food.cartQuantity= 0;
   //         } else {
     //           Food.cartQuantity = Food.cartQuantity - 1;
     //       }
      //      etquantity.setText("" + Food.cartQuantity);
            updateQuantity(position,listViewHolder.etquantity,-1);
       }
   });
    return customView;
}
```

Comment: your adapter has strings, not food. That's what the error is trying to tell you

Comment: from the stack trace, it looks like you are trying to turn a `string` into `com.xxxx.Food`. Start there.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.xxxx.Food` You can't convert a bicycle into a monkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only passing the `foodname` as an array to your adapter and then trying to cast the `foodname`(which is a `string`) into your `Food` object inside your adapter which is definitely not possible.

Solution : create an arraylist using `Food` and then pass this arraylist to your adapter

or if you just need to print the `foodname` inside your adapter, just add like this

```
final String foodname=(String)getItem(position);
listViewHolder.tvfoodname.setText(foodname);
```

********* **UPDATE** *********

Create an arraylist like this

```
ArrayList<Food> food_data=new ArrayList<>();
```

and then populate it like this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
{
JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
String name=obj.getString("foodname");
String quantity=obj.getString("add_json_key_for_quantity");
Food food=new Food();
food.setFoodname(name);
food.seCartQuantity(quantity);
food_data.add(food);
}

BaseAdapter ListAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,food_data);
listView2.setAdapter(ListAdapter);
```

now change the adapter constructor

```
    ArrayList<Food> food_data=new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;
CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Food> food_data) {
    //super(context, R.layout.item_food, stringlist);
    this.context = context;
    this.food_data = food_data;
}
```

Now it can be accessed like this

```
final Food foods=food_data.get(position);
listViewHolder.tvfoodname.setText(foods.getFoodname());
listViewHolder.etquantity.setText(foods.getCartQuantity);
```

- note : remember to declare appropriate getters/setters

Comment: How should i pass the arraylist to adapter?

Comment: just create an arryalist of type `Food` like you have created for `String` then initialise your `Food` object from response and finally add it to the created arraylist

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast String type into Food type object which are incompatible. 
Try :

```
Food food = new Food();
food.setFoodName(getItem(position))
```

..and so on  for other attributes of Food model.
My suggestion is to create List of type Food at the time of parsing and then pass it to your CustomList adapter.

Hope it helps.